# Why does compiling a standard priority queue for my object class fail?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, priority-queue, std-pair

I'm trying to create a `std::priority_queue` that takes as parameters a pair. The pair has parameters int and `Coord`. `Coord` is a struct simply containing two ints (x and y) for coordinates for an array.

What I'm trying to do with my entire program is implementing the Dijkstra algorithm on an array grid (instead of using a graph), which is already giving me a headache because I'm not really sure I'm doing it the correct way. At least I'm trying and learning. But anyway the problem I'm having now is that when I compile, I get the error

> "C2678 binary'<' no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of
>   type 'const Coord' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

This is how some of my code looks like:

```
struct Coord
{
    int x, y;
};
```

this is the basic `Coord` struct. Then there's the function where I create the queue:

```
void dijkstraFirstPhase(Coord start, Coord end, int(&aGrid)[HEIGHT][WIDTH], unordered_map<pair<int, int>, bool, pair_hash>& theMap)
{
    //priority_queue< pair<int, pair<int, int>> > pq;
    priority_queue<pair<int, Coord>> pq; //this is the line where the error comes from

    //initializing the starting point
    int distanceFromStart = 0;
    aGrid[start.x][start.y] = distanceFromStart;
    pq.push({ distanceFromStart, start });

    while (!pq.empty())
    {
        Coord u = pq.top().second;
        theMap[make_pair(u.x, u.y)] = true;
        pq.pop();

        writeDistances(u.x, u.y, aGrid, theMap, pq);
        displayGrid(aGrid);

        if (theMap[make_pair(end.x, end.y)] = true)
        {
            cout << "The end has been found" << endl;
            cout << "Distance written into its cell: " << aGrid[end.x][end.y] << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to know how to get rid of this error, I'm not very familiar with queues or pairs, but I thought I understood them enough for what I needed to do. What is it trying to compare with that operator? I don't need an int to be smaller than the `Coord` in the pair arguments.

Any suggestions are welcome, but not complex one as I'm still a beginner with C++ and might not understand them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may seem entirely logical to you, but the compiler has no idea what *order* your conceptual definition of "priority" means regarding your thing called a `Coord`. Your objects being stored in your queue look like this:

```
std::pair<int, Coord>
```

and understanding how `std::priority_queue` compares elements is warranted.

The adapter [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) defaults to using [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) for the item comparator to determine order. As you have now-discovered, that comparator does little more than manufacture a simple *`a < b`* construct to compare objects for order, and if the object class (or its bases) provide this, great; if not, you need to do so. as it turns out, [`std::pair` *does* provide an `operator <`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp), which basically establishes strict weak ordering across `first` and `second`. For two pair objects it essentially does this:

```
return lhs.first < rhs.first || (!(rhs.first < lhs.first) && lhs.second < rhs.second);
```

Why is *that* important? Note that `second` usage in the last expression. It's important because the `second` in the above is of *your* type `Coord`, Therefore, `operator <` is being applied to `Coord` and since there is no such operator, compiler = not-happy.

As a side-note, you've noticed this *works* out of the box for `std::pair<int, std::pair<int,int>>` because as mentioned earlier, `std::pair` has an operator <`overload, and in that case two different instantiations of`operator <` are manifested.

To solve this, you have to provide such an `operator` for your type. There are essentially only two ways to do this: a member function or a free-function either of which define a `operator <` overload for `Coord`. Usually implemented as a member function, but also possible as a free-function, this essentially provides the operator `std::less` is looking for. This is the most common mechanism for providing order (and imho the easiest to understand):

```
// member function
struct Coord
{
    int x, y;

    bool operator <(const Coord& rhs)
    {
        return x < rhs.x || (!(rhs.x < x) && y < rhs.y)
    }
};
```

or

```
// free function
bool operator <(const Coord& lhs, const Coord& rhs)
{
    return lhs.x < rhs.x || (!(rhs.x < lhs.x) && lhs.y < rhs.y)
}
```

---

**General Comparator Guidelines**

Beyond making `std::less<>` happy for a given type by overloading `operator <`, many containers, adapters, and algorithms allow you to provide your own custom comparator type. For example:

- `std::map`
- `std::set`
- `std::sort`
- `std::priority_queue`
- many others...

To that, there are several possible ways to do this. Examples include:

- Provide an `operator <` for instances of your `Type` type (easy, example shown prior). This allows the continued default `std::less` to do it's job of firing `operator <` that is provided by you.
- Provide a comparator to the container/algorithm that performs the comparison for you (also easy). In essence you're writing a replacement for `std::less` that *you* specify for the container, adapater, or algorithm when declaring or invoking them.
- Provide a template specialization of `std::less<Coord>` (moderately easy, but rarely done and less intuitive for beginners). This *replaces* `std::less` with your specialization wherever it would normally be used.

Examples of the last two appear below. We'll assume we're just using your `Coord` rather than your `std::pair<int, Coord>`, explained earlier

**Provide custom comparator**

You don't have to use `std::less` for ordering. You can also provide your own functor that does the same job. The third template parameter to `std::priority_queue` is what you use to provide this:

```
struct CoordLess
{
    bool operator()(Coord const& lhs, Coord const& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.x < rhs.x || (!(rhs.x < lhs.x) && lhs.y < rhs.y)
    }
};

std::priority_queue<Coord, std::vector<Coord>, CoordLess> myqueue;
```

This is handy when you need to implement different orderings on the same object class for different containers. For example, you could have one container that orders small-to-large, another large-to-small. Different comparators allow you to do that. For example, you could create a `std::set` of `Coord` objects with your comparator by doing

```
std::set<Coord, CoordLess> myset;
```

or sort a vector `vec` of `Coord` objects by doing this:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), CoordLess());
```

Note in both cases we specify at declaration or invocation the custom comparator.

**Provide a `std::less` specialization**

This is not as easy to understand, rarely done, but just as easy to implement. Since `std::less` is the default comparator, so long as the type is a custom type (not a native language type or library type) you can provide a `std::less` specialization for `Coord`. This means *everything* that normally uses `std::less<Coord>` for ordering will get this implicitly if the definition below is provided beforehand.

```
namespace std
{
    template<>
    struct less<Coord>
    {
        bool operator ()(Coord const& lhs, Coord const& rhs) const
        {
            return lhs.x < rhs.x || (!(rhs.x < lhs.x) && lhs.y < rhs.y)
        }
    };
}
```

With that provided (usually immediately after your custom type in the same header), you can simply use default template parameters, whereas before we had to specify them. For example now we can declare a `std::set` like this:

```
std::set<Coord> myset;
```

or perform a sort like this:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Both of those default to using `std::less<Coord>` and since we've specialized that ourselves, it uses *ours*. This is a handy, enveloping way of changing default behavior in *many* places, but with great power comes great responsibility, so be careful, and *never* do this with native or library-provided types.

Hopefully that give you some ideas on different ways you can solve your error.

Comment: That was absolutely fantastic. Very exhaustive answer, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a comparison operation for your `Coord` class.  Add a `bool operator<(const Coord &rhs) const;` to your class that will determine which of the two Coords (*this or rhs) comes first.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, yet I don't think I know which of the two should come first and how exactly to write it inside the operator overloading function. Would greatly appreciate a more in-depth explanation so I can understand it properly for the future as well